# Prevent iOS from closing background app

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I use an app called "GPS Tracks" to track my movements throughout the day with my iPhone 6 on iOS 9.2.1. The app often shuts down while it is actively recording in the background, which the developer indicated is something that happens when memory runs low.

Is there anything I can do to either 1) prevent iOS from shutting down a specific app for memory reasons or 2) tell iOS which apps to shut down first or 3) be warned when the app is closed by iOS.

I am ready to jailbreak it if necessary.

Comment: Why not keep the app open even if it means keeping the screen on or setting Auto-Lock to Never?

Comment: I use the App all day to record my movements in the background, so this isn't possible.